# Upload image AJAX - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, form-data

Hello i'm trying to upload images to Laravel from AJAX using FormData() method. I think i'm sending good the file because if I send a file that excess the size (2mb) the server is answering me with validation error but when I send with good image properties its not saving it, I don't know why and I'm not getting any error in console, the status code is 200 OK.

I already look for another post but didnt work :/

this is part of my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#uploadimage").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('#mensaje').empty()
    $('#loading').show()
    var token  = $('#token').val()

    $.ajax({
      url: '/admin/imagenes',
      headers:  {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
      },
      type: 'POST',
      data: ({
        type: 'post',
        formData: new FormData(this)
      }),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#loading').hide()
        $('#message').html(data)
      }
```

and this is my Laravel code:

```
public function store(Request $request)    {
  if ($request->file('file')) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = 'NacionGrita_' .time(). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = base_path(). '/imagenes/articulos';
    $file->move($path, $name);

    $imagen = new Imagen();
    $imagen->url = $name;

    $imagen->save();

    return response()->json(
      $file->toArray()
    );
  }

}
```

And this my Blade code:

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => 'admin.imagenes.store', 'id' => 'uploadimage', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true])!!}
<div class="form-group ">
  {!!Form::label('file', 'Imagen principal')!!}
  {!!Form::file('file', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'file','placeholder' => 'Ingrese el título del post', 'required'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
  {!!Form::submit('Agregar Artículo', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary submit', 'id' => 'upImg'])!!}
</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
</div>
```

I hope anyone can help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try this method..It is working..That is Before you send data from ajax called, convert your image as Base64 and then you can pass that Base64 code via ajax called and then on Controller You can decode that code into normal image..and then you can save it..Try it...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to implement this plugin:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

It allows you to send files via Ajax with jquery.